# Configure Spring Boot to use my Gmail smtp

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, gmail

Is there any way to replace the following code by an entry in the application.properties file:

Properties props = this.mailSender.getJavaMailProperties(); props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just put these on application.properties. Others things as is.

```
#SMTP configuration
    spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
    spring.mail.port=587
    spring.mail.username=klklk@gmail.com
    spring.mail.password=lkkl
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

Write mail sender class like this

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {
    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;
    private final String imageLink = "images/teddy.jpeg";
    private final String imageNameToSend = "teddy.jpeg";

    @Override
    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = null;
        try {
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);


            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);

            FileSystemResource file
                    = new FileSystemResource(new ClassPathResource(imageLink).getFile());
            helper.addAttachment(imageNameToSend, file);

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(text, "text/html");


            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);
            emailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException | IOException e ) {
            log.info("Exception catched {}",e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Email Service will be like this

```
public interface EmailService {
    void sendSimpleMessage(
            String to, String subject, String text) throws IOException, MessagingException;
}
```

Add following library to build.gradle file or if you  are using another build tool add this library to corresponding file

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:1.5.9.RELEASE')
```

Comment: doesn't work, I got the following error:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k4sm31119026wrx.91 - gsmtp
] with root cause

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k4sm31119026wrx.91 - gsmtp

Comment: try with spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false

Comment: check my updated code and follow this. you can take a look on this project also https://github.com/sanjoy-sust/FreightManagement/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/fm/assignment/mail